# Use ObjectMapper to parse Dictionary within a Dictionary Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary, objectmapper

My old JSON structure was like this:

```
{
"parameters": {
"customerId": 9,
"from": "2014-06-05T14:00:00",
"until": "2014-06-05T15:00:00",
"km": 20,
"insurance": false
},
"estimatesPerCategory": {
  "2": {
  "timeCost": 5,
  "kmCost": 6,
  ... 
 }
```

To parse JSON I use [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper).
This code works very well:

```
if let myObject = Mapper<CostEstimateResult>().map(JSONObject: JSON) {

}
```

The class CostEstimateResult looks like this.

```
class CostEstimateResult : NSObject, Mappable {

var parameters:CostEstimateParameters?
var estimatesPerCategory:[String: CostEstimate]? // CostEstimate.id -> CostEstimate


override init() {}

required convenience init?(map: Map) {
    self.init()
    self.mapping(map: map)
}

 func mapping(map: Map) {
    estimatesPerCategory <- map["estimatesPerCategory"]
    parameters <- map["parameters"]
 }
}
```

And last but not least my CostEstimate class for estimatesPerCategory

```
class CostEstimate : NSObject, Mappable {

var timeCost:NSNumber?
...
override init() {}

required convenience init?(map: Map) {
    self.init()
    self.mapping(map: map)
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    timeCost <- map["timeCost"]
    ...
    }
}
```

This is working. The mapper in CostEstimateResult will call the mapper in CostEstimates and I get my parsed data.

Now I changed the JSON Structure:

```
{
"parameters": {
//same like before
},
"estimatesPerCategory": {
 "2": {
  "total": {
    "preTax": {
      "value": 1,
      "text": "1,00 €"
    },
    "configTax": false
  }, 
 "3": {
     //same...
   }
 }
}
```

In my opinion in the basic structure nothing changes. `estimatesPerCategory` is still the same dictionary. The data behind `estimatesPerCategory` are changed, okay.

The problem is, when I call the mapper `...Mapper<CostEstimateResult>().map...` the parameters will be parse, but not the costEstimates. **The `func mapping` in `CostEstimate` isn't call anymore**.

Long story short: It seems that the type of `estimatesPerCategory` in `CostEstimateResult` changes with the json structure. I can't figure out which type I need.

Answer (score 0):

Now with new JSON Structure, your `Class CostEstimate` structure will be changed and a new Class `PreTax` will be required to be created:

```
class CostEstimateResult : NSObject, Mappable {

    var parameters:CostEstimateParameters?
    var estimatesPerCategory:[String: CostEstimate]? // CostEstimate.id -> CostEstimate

    override init() {}

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
        self.mapping(map: map)
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        estimatesPerCategory <- map["estimatesPerCategory"]
    }
}


class CostEstimate : NSObject, Mappable {
    var total:totalTax?

    override init() {}

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
        self.mapping(map: map)
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        total <- map["total"]
    }
}

class totalTax : NSObject, Mappable {
    var preTax:PreTax?
    var configTax:Bool?

    override init() {}

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
        self.mapping(map: map)
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        preTax <- map["preTax"]
        configTax <- map["configTax"]
    }
}

class PreTax : NSObject, Mappable {

    var value:NSNumber?
    var text:String?

    override init() {}

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
        self.mapping(map: map)
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        value <- map["value"]
        text <- map["text"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it doesn't work, because the mapper of CostEstimate isn't call and I don't know why.
Why do I have to parse PreTax? I have to parse Total first, haven't I?

Comment: How did you test it? I copied your code and I understand the structure. It looks fine, but my main problem is that `estimatesPerCategory <- map["estimatesPerCategory"]` this line doens't execute the `CostEstimate` class. And I have no idea why

Comment: I created an array and converted in to JSON and did Parsing with ObjectMapper and I was able to access all values. Try removing `NSObject` and `override init() {}`

Comment: Doesn't work for me neither. Would you send me your testproject or put it on github? I will have a look and post (if I find) the solution here. My mail is: snoopybig@gmx.de

Comment: check this temporary file(expires in 48 hours) : https://expirebox.com/download/4354f00862abaca70b4140c82081ceec.html